# How to unit test the global.asax file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

In my application some variables are initialized when application start .i.e in global.aspx file

```
Application_start() 
{
    //velocityhelper.TemplateLocatio is static class.
    VelocityHelper.TemplateLocation = ConfigurationHelper.ContentLocation + "/"
        + ConfigurationHelper.CultureId + "/" + "Templates/";    
}
```

When we access the templatelocation variable it will returns null always. Can you please let me know how to initailze this template location.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot unit test the code inside Global.asax because you need an HttpApplication in order to execute it. What you could do on the other hand is to put this code in a separate method and then unit test this method.